# Searching array is not returning any results

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have the following code that is suppose to search an array :

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.passwordList.Length; i++)

       {

            string userInput = Convert.ToString(this.passInput);

            if(userInput == passwordList[i])
            {

                MessageBox.Show("FOUND");
                foundResult = 1;
                break;

            }
            //MessageBox.Show();


        }
```

and the array has the following results :

```
public string[] passwordList = {"123456", "145784" , "asasas"};
```

What am I doing wrong!?!?

Comment: What is `passInput`??  By your conversion to a string method, I'm guessing that you may be a little mixed up on your datatypes.  Try debugging and stepping through your code to see exactly what values your variables are set to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mistake is probably here:

```
string userInput = Convert.ToString(this.passInput);
```

If you have a WinForms control, try something like this instead:

```
string userInput = this.passInput.Text;
```

You might also want to inspect the value of `userInput` in a debugger to make sure that it contains the value that you expect.

Comment: Thanks, its right!!! silly mistake from my side... will accept your question when Stackoverflow allows me

Comment: Your ToString() will return something like `"System.Windows.Forms.TextBox, Text: actual input"`

Answer (score 1):

You havn't provided information about all your variables, but I suspect the the line

```
string userInput = Convert.ToString(this.passInput);
```

is the problem. If `this.passInput` is a control you will get the name of the type of the control and not what the user entered into the control.

If that is true you can simplify your code into something like this:

```
if (passwordList.Contains(this.passInput.Text)) {
  MessageBox.Show("FOUND");  
  foundResult = 1;  
}
```